# Proximity tracking using RFID

Tags: rfid, proximity-sensor

I would like to build a proximity tracking system. A a central unit small enough to fit on a key chain or necklace that would be able to detect as soon as a tagged object is farther away than a dozen or so feet.

I was thinking the central unit would consisting of a Arduino Mini and some sort of RFID reader. I would use semi-passive RFID tags since passive tags wouldn't be able to provide the range I need.

I haven't been able to find much information on semi-passive RFID tags. Would I be able to get the range I need with the form factor constraint I have? How can I obtain some semi-passive tags? I wasn't able to find any on digikey or any information on designing them myself.

Will I need to use fully active tags? Or maybe there's a better solution that doesn't use RFID?

Comment: Look up the University of Washington and also the topic, generally, of *ambient backscatter*. No licensing requirements, can get a range of about where you are considering, very simple in concept (if not in the software implementation.) Very low power (almost zero.)

Comment: @jonk *Ambient backscatter* does look like a very interesting concept but everything I've read puts the range at a max of 2.5 feet. The absolute minimum for my application is 5 feet and I would prefer more like 10+.

Comment: I've heard that implementations have reached 10 ft, perhaps a little more. But this is an area I plan to experiment with next year. Not yet. So I don't know more than what I've read, so far.

Comment: @jonk You don't happen to know where you read that? The only project I can seem to find is the original one. Even if it doesn't work for this project I'm very interested in following the technology.

Comment: How big would you consider the antennas/coils (at both ends of the link) could be - the bigger the better. If you are talking just a few centimetres then it's unlikely this will ever work over the distance you propose. Directionality is a big problem usually. Certain directions will obtain max coupled energy, other directions will be zero.

Comment: @RedHatter I don't recall where I read that, but if I find it again and remember this thread, I'll post it here. Be aware that UofW isn't the only source of info (though they seem to want to be.) (I've written them directly and they are *not helpful* to others, in my opinion. I think they are trying to protect some idea of intellectual property and this prevents them from much help or cooperation.) But see, for example: [HitchHike: Practical Backscatter Using Commodity WiFi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tmatoD0I1o). Look for other sources of info. Not everyone is being obstructive.